# Angle between two position vectors on a sphere

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I'm trying to find a general formula for the dot product of two position vectors of two points on a unit sphere given their latitude and longitude coordinates but I'm not sure how to find the angle between the vectors. Could someone help me figure it out?

Comment: Do you know how to convert spherical coordinates into Cartesian?

Comment: When you say latitude and longitude, do you mean spherical coordinates? If yes, then it is pretty simple to convert them into cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose WLOG the radius of the sphere is 1. Let $(\phi, \theta)$ be the latitude and longitude coordinates.

1. Convert from latitude/longitude to cartesian coordinates.

$(\phi, \theta) \mapsto (\cos \phi \cos \theta, \cos \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi)$

2. Take the dot product in cartesian coordinates.

One can show (exercise) that for points $(\phi_1, \theta_1)$ and $(\phi_2, \theta_2)$ that the answer works out to be $\sin \phi_1 \sin \phi_2 + \cos \phi_1 \cos \phi_2 \cos (\theta_1 - \theta_2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I followed your instructions and converted the geographic coordinates into cartesian and then took the dot product. After factorising the first two terms, I used the compound angle theorem and I got this: cos(phi1)cos(phi2)cos(theta1-theta2)+sin(phi1)sin(phi2) Could you show me some working so I know where I went wrong?

Comment: @FarmerZee In fact, you were correct. I simply forgot to type the $\cos \phi_2$ term. I'm editing the post to correct it.